# drawing a rectangle for a bitmap clone

Tags: c#, system.drawing, bitmapimage

I have a bitmap in which i clone and specify a rectangle - the current rectangle has certain width and height values which i've used for checking the rectangle for a QR code. I noticed this checks the top left corner. I would i be able to alter this to check for top right corner, bottom right and left corners of the same size(width and height)?

```
 Bitmap result = fullImg.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 375, 375), fullImg.PixelFormat);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
for (int pg = 0; pg < inputDocument.PageCount; pg++)
            {

                string workGif = workingFilename.Replace(".pdf", string.Format(".{0}.gif", pg + 1));
                GhostscriptWrapper.GeneratePageThumb(workingFilename, workGif, pg + 1, 300, 300); // size (last two params) does not seem to have any effect
                using (var fullImg = new Bitmap(workGif))
                {  
                        Bitmap result = fullImg.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 375, 375), fullImg.PixelFormat);
                        string QRinfo = Process(result);
                        MessageBox.Show(QRinfo);

                        string[] qcode = QRinfo.Split('/');
                        string gid = qcode[qcode.Count() - 1];
                        Guid pgGuid = new Guid(gid);
                }        
            }
```

Process Method for qr

```
public string Process(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        var reader = new com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeReader();

        try
        {
            LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bitmap, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
            var binarizer = new HybridBinarizer(source);
            var binBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(binarizer);
            return reader.decode(binBitmap).Text;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly you would achieve with this? A rectangle have a Point and a Size, and a Point is always calculated considering the top-left position.

Comment: @GuFigueiredo I am trying to figure out a way to detect a qr code on a page and depending on its location i want to rotate it so that the qr code is on the top left corner. How can i look for a qr code in the whole page and finding its location to rotate?

Comment: Can you provide more information? You have the qr codes in a Windows Form or is an ASP.NET page? How these elements are loaded in the control?

Comment: @GuFigueiredo I added more code for my work and this is a windows forms. Basically it is a scanned pdf which has a qr code on it. I am to scan for the qr code and rotate the document rightside up so that the qr code is located on the top left corner. I would really like your help in any way i've thinking and working around this for hours . thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the QRCodes are ALWAYS on the corners, you can use a picturebox for the Bitmap, and then rotate it using the RotateFlip method:

```
Bitmap bp = new Bitmap("myImage.jpg");
pictureBox1.Image = bp;
bp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
pictureBox1.Invalidate();
```

Comment: since i am not using a picturebox and won't be using one i could go ahead with the rotateflip?

Comment: You can make a test with the RotateFlip. I think will work, because RotateFlip is a method of Bitmap, not PictureBox.

Comment: this works but takes me back to my original problem after fixing its rotation. It passes into the process method the original image not the rotated it seems like